# Responsive website / Media queries issue with iPhone 3G and Xperia X8

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm currently annoyed by my media queries to target smartphones. It's the first time I use media queries.

I've done a tablet version (768px) of a website, and a phone version (320px).

[image: tablet version, firefox screenshot]

### [image: smartphone version, firefox screenshot]

Note that theses screenshots are actually Firefox screenshots.
As you can see, these displays work fine when I resize my window on Firefox, IE, Webkit.

However, the display is wrong on my iPhone 3G and my Xperia X8.

Here are the results (left iPhone, right Xperia) :

### [image]

As far as I know, both phones have a 480*320 pixels resolution.
So, why such results?

On the iPhone screen, the light brown rectangle on the header is supposed to be 300px width. Why is it so small?

And why is the tablet version loaded on the Xperia ?

I use these media queries on my CSS :

/* Tablets ----------- */

```
@media  (min-width: 768px) and (max-width:1023px)
```

/* Phones */

```
@media (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width:767px),
        (min-width: 320px) and (max-width:767px)
```

I hope you'll can help me, I'm stuck on this issue since too much days.

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  For example, tagging with `media` and `query` does not mean that you are talking about CSS media queries.  Be sure to select tags carefully, based on their short descriptions in the tag selection field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you setup a proper viewport?  Like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0" />
```

Put that in your head tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use proper media Queries to ensure the perfect rendering and responsiveness for smart phones and cross platforms. here is the link you can learn how to use media queries in right way. [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)